# Is there any way to give an absolute position to an internal element of an SVG?

Tags: css, svg, scroll, css-position, mobile-safari

I am using an inline SVG, and I'd like for one part of it (`<g>`) to be positioned absolutely, rather than with respect to its parent elements.

In HTML, the equivalent would be:

```
#objectID{
  position:fixed;
  top:100px;
  left:100px;
}
```

I am trying to create an effect where the overall SVG scrolls with the page, but one part of it floats without scrolling.

Currently, I am using scroll events to move the element in the opposite direction by the same amount.

But, on mobile browsers, scroll events are not fired frequently enough and the result is jerky (on desktop it's fine).

Obviously the floating element can't move outside the bounding box, but is there any way to position it relative to the HTML container outside the SVG, instead of relative to the SVG?

Separating it into two SVG's is not an option for this particular project.

I am guessing that this is not possible, but it will save me an enormous amount of work if it is.

Comment: Discounting that you seem to think of `position: fixed` for HTML, no, there is no way to fulfill all of your requirements. Elements in SVG are always positioned in relation to some viewport, and the root `<svg>` elements [always](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/coords.html#ViewportSpace) defines a viewport.

Comment: Split it into two separate SVG's (or three if you want the floating part to move between the parts of the other SVG.

Comment: Yes, I meant `fixed`good catch. Thanks for the link. I'm too tired to understand it all today but I'll read through it tomorrow. In my case, the SVG is always the same size as the HTML element, so there may be something I can figure out.